# control child popup page from parent page with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using vb.net on an aspx code behind event, is there away to tell from a parent page if the child page popup is open, and then close the child page if it is truly open based on some event on the parent page, like clicking a gridview edit link, again?

SOLVED: I have no way to close this issue so I am posting a link to the solution I used...A jQuery plugin caled BlockUI which prevent access to the parent page until the child page is closed. Genius!!
[jQuery BlockUI link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187658/blockui-jquery-on-button-click)

Comment: Couldn't you use javascript? Why does it have to be vb.net?

Comment: I don't have an issue with java script just not very proficient. I use it now to open the child page....ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "ClientScript1", scriptText1, False)

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you could open the window and keep a reference to it then use the reference to close it. If it's already closed it shouldn't make a difference really. See

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1365017

I don't think vb.net is going to help you much to be honest. The only way i can think of getting vb.net in the mix is get the child window to set a hidden field on child window open then use this value to register a javascript start up method which will close the window. Seems over engineered to me.