# BlockUI jQuery on Button click

Tags: jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

**ANSWER**: The fix for this problem is this :

Change selector from `$('#Button3')` to `$('#<%= Button3.ClientID %>')`

Thanks to Yuri.

**ISSUE**:

I am trying to get a button `click` to run the [JQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/). I am having some issues this is my first shot at JQuery. I do have the Hello World pop-up example working so I think I am close but could use some help getting the rest worked out.

Here is the code...

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#Button3").click(function() {
     $.blockUI();

     setTimeout(function() {
         $.unblockUI({
             onUnblock: function() { alert('onUnblock'); }
         });
     }, 2000);
   });
});

</script>
```

I am trying to run this on an aspx page. As stated the Hello World popup works but not the blockUI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the button aspx...

```
 <td>
      <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </td>
```

no code behind events on the button.

This apsx page has a Master Page as well.

Some tweaks to the code have prodcued this error when closing the page in Visual Studio...

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of
>   type 'Sys._Application' cannot be converted to type
>   'Sys._Application'. Parameter name: instance

Comment: what version of JQuery and Jquery BlockUI are you using

Comment: jquery-1.2.6.js, I have also tried jquery-1.7.js   and BlockUI was downloaded today, can not find a rev.

Comment: Finally got dev PC online.  * jQuery blockUI plugin
 * Version 2.39 (23-MAY-2011)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3 or later

Comment: @are you using an asp:Button, asp:LinkButton? do they have click events? please show your button's markup and also the asp.net version.

Comment: This apsx page has a Master Page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to block the UI. then only will it be unblocked. You cannot unblocked something that is not blocked as *unblocked == not blocked*.

So uncomment the first line inside the button click event of your code.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/D9GCj/1/

Please note that `asp:Button` will be rendered as `input type="submit"`

Comment: Sorry the commented out part was for other testing I need to fix my post.

Comment: uh-oh. i forgot the most trivial question. which browser are you testing the code with?

Comment: Internet Exploreer 9, this is an ASP button.

Answer (score 1):

check out http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/F53gd/

It works with the

- [JQuery 1.6.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js)
- [BlockUI v 2.3](http://andrewhays.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/js/jquery.blockUI.js)

Comment: please note that asp:net renders as type="submit" and not "type=button"

Comment: Do I need an AJAX Script Manager on the page? This is on an ASPX page inside of a ContntPlaceholder, it is still not working but the Hello World sample is working. can't figure this out.

Comment: Tried these versions and I am getting same no results. But Hello World popup is still working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(onRequestStart)
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onRequestEnd)
    }
);

function onRequestStart() {
    $.blockUI();
}

function onRequestEnd() {
    $.unblockUI();
}
```

Button OnClick:

```
Protected Sub OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Button1.Text = "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually wanted to fire the BlockUI on an Edit click event of a gridview which opens a popup apsx page. And of course unblock when the Child Popup page is submitted back to parent page.